# How can I filter a list within a dataframe to contain only unique values?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary, set

I have a data frame titled 'CPC' which looks like this:

```
location_code  sitc_product_code                                                 
ABW            [0711, 0711, 6996, 6996, 7284, 7492, 7492, 749...
AFG            [0711, 1110, 7188, 7284, 7284, 7423, 7423, 749...
AGO            [0711, 0711, 0711, 0711, 0711, 0711, 0711, 699...
AIA            [7188, 7492, 8743, 8947, 7641, 7649, 7783, 778...
ALB            [0585, 1110, 7188, 7239, 7239, 7239, 7492, 749...
...                                                          ...
WSM            [7284, 7284, 7284, 0341, 0341, 0341, 6424, 682...
YEM            [0711, 0711, 0711, 0711, 0711, 0711, 1110, 699...
ZAF            [0585, 0585, 0585, 0585, 0585, 0585, 0585, 058...
ZMB            [0711, 0711, 0711, 0711, 0711, 0711, 0711, 071...
ZWE            [0585, 0585, 0585, 0585, 0585, 0585, 0585, 058...
```

The second column of the data frame, titled "sitc_product_code" contains one list in each row.
Currently, each list contains duplicate entries, e.g. row ABW contains "0711" twice and "6996" twice. How can I filter the lists within each row to contain only unique values?

I tried something like this:

```
CPC['sitc_product_code'] = set(CPC.sitc_product_code)
```

Which didn't work. This has really stumped me so I'd really appreciate some help.

Follow up question, once the lists within this data frame contain only unique values, how can I convert the data frame to a dictionary such that the location codes are the keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to apply `set` for every row. you can use :

`CPC['sitc_product_code'].apply(lambda row : list(set(row)))`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much! Do you also know how I can convert this to a dictionary?

Comment: What do you want to convert to a dictionnary ?

Comment: as suggested above, I have applied the following code:
```
CPC = CPC['sitc_product_code'].apply(lambda row : sorted(list(set(row))))
```
which gives me a data frame that looks very similar to the original post. Now I would like to use the location codes from the first column as keys of a dictionary where each element of the dictionary contains the lists from the second column, How can I accomplish this?

Comment: i would assume there is something to do with `CPC.to_dict()`

Comment: it was as simple as:
``` dictCPC = CPC.to_dict() ``` which worked perfectly.